# can't set up alias for lab directory but can set up alias for phpMyAdmin in lion

Tags: macos, apache, web, osx-lion, alias

I am using mac with osx lion
I set up alias for my apache using the following setting:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin/ "/Users/jason/Sites/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "/Users/jason/Sites/phpMyAdmin">
    Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /Lab8/ "/Users/jason/Sites/Lab8/"
<Directory "/Users/jason/Sites/Lab8">
    Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My Lab8 directory and phpMyAdmin Directory are placed in the same place  (/Users/jason/Sites)

I can access the phpMyAdmin though **localhost/phpMyAdmin/**
But when I want to access the Lab8 directory though **localhost/Lab8/**
It give the following message:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /Lab8/ on this server.

I don't know what wrong with my setting.
I cannot access my Lab8 directory though **localhost/Lab8** 
even I set permission 777 for the Lab8 directory and all files under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you have directory listing off, and there is no index.php/index.html file in the Lab8 directory?

Comment: I figured out this long time ago but thanks for your answer :)